# Using Over() with aggregate functions while calculating percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, aggregate-functions, percentage

I am writing a query to print Total Students in each department in a college, I also want to print the percentage of those students in each department out of Total students in the college.

```
select dep.[Id] as DepId, dep.[Name] as Department, COUNT(s.[Id]) as [TotalStudents]
    , COUNT(S.[Id]) * 100/NULLIF(COUNT(COUNT(S.[Id]) OVER(), 0) AS [Percentage]
from dbo.[Department] dep
left join dbo.[student] s on dep.[Id] = s.[DepartmentId]
group by dep.[Id], dep.[Name]
```

Having issues with calculating percentage, the above query throwing an error

> dbo.Student.Id is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function.

If there are Total 10 students across all Departments and Dep1 has 5 students then the percentage should be 50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions like that, but you would need a window `SUM` of the counts, not a window `COUNT()`. I would also recommend putting a decimal value in the computation, to avoid integer division:

```
select d.[Id] as DepId, d.[Name] as Department, 
    count(s.[Id]) as [TotalStudents], 
    count(s.[Id]) * 100.0 / nullif(sum(count(s.[Id])) over(), 0) AS [Percentage]
from dbo.[Department] d
left join dbo.[student] s on d.[Id] = s.[DepartmentId]
group by d.[Id], d.[Name]
```